# In Google Analytics 4 (GA4) how can I see page views by path and querystring when only "Page path and screen class" is available?

Tags: google-analytics-4, pageviews, querystringparameter

In GA4 Reports > Engagement > Pages and screens, above the list of pages viewed, there is a dropdown with the following options:

- Page title and screen class
- Page path and screen class
- Page title and screen name
- Content group

The option that is missing (mentioned in various sources on the internet) is "Page path + querystring".

This is the same on several GA4 websites I manage (all upgraded from GA to GA4)

Any ideas on how to enable the missing option?

Comment: I do not think this is possible, because the page path + query is [not compatible](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/11608978) . Certainly if you edit the report and add that metric and try to use that metric, you get a blank screen and the incompatible warning Editing the report is done by:

1. click the pencil icon in the top right
2. In the Customise report pane, click the Dimensions option.
3. The 4 available dimensions you describe are shown.
4. You can add the page path + query string dimension to this list and then it becomes available as an option.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

On left hand side, click "Explore" option. Then hit "Free form"

Now on left hand side you have dimensions and metric. For dimension you need to choose page path + querystring and click import on top right corner, and for metric "Views" under "Page/screen"
Like so:
[image]

Once that is done, you need to drag & drop or select that dimension under Rows, and under Values that metric. So for Rows select page path & query string, and for Values select Views. Like so:
[image]

This is very similar to what google data studio offers, but it is embedded in GA4, and somehow works way faster, and have more options ex. pathing. Also took me a while to figure how to display such data.

Comment: Well that is helpful yes, but it doesn't answer the question. The reports are better than the  explorations in a number of ways so it would be good if this was in reports. I suggest that everyone uses the Send Feedback to Google option to ask for the page + query to be added.